# What does it mean to reduce tax on Lump Sum payments, rather than Salary?

Tags: income-tax, canada, canada-revenue-agency

See screenshot from the CRA [T1213](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/forms-publications/forms/t1213.html). In requesting to reduce the tax withholding from an employment payment, you can select either 'Lump sum' or 'Salary'.

What does "Lump sum" mean? How is it different from "Salary"?

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

A Lump-Sum payment is what it sounds like. A single payment of money, typically a bonus, or as mentioned there, payout of unused vacation, perhaps severance pay, etc.

The point is that you might want to reduce your tax withholdings on all regular salary payments [likely because you are making consistent RRSP contributions on your own, and want the tax benefit immediately]. OR, you might want to only reduce your tax withholding on a lump-sum payment [likely because you want to make a single RRSP contribution from your bonus, for example].

If you receive a $5k bonus, and want to commit to making a $5k RRSP contribution, that is very different than wanting to make a $5k contribution every month! So the CRA allows you to clarify.